# unit testing login component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular7

I want to unit test for login component. I am using reactive forms and Angular 7.

I created backend fake service I am calling that services. I tried below code but I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'debugElement' of undefined

How to call login method and how to subscribe that value?

Please anyone help me on that.

signin.component.html

```
     <form
        class="form"
        (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
        [formGroup]="signinForm"
        novalidate>
        <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
          <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="25" fxFlex.gt-sm="25">
            <mat-card>
              <mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-title class="_mat-title">
                  <h5>Sign In</h5>
                </mat-card-title>
              </mat-card-header>
              <mat-card-content>
                <div
                  fxLayout="row wrap"
                  fxLayout.xs="column"
                  fxLayoutAlign="space-between stretch">
                  <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="100">
                    <mat-form-field>
                      <input
                        matInput
                        placeholder="Username(Email)"
                        formControlName="username"
                        value="{{username}}"
                        />
                      <mat-error
                        *ngIf="submitted &&
                        !signinForm.controls['username'].errors?.required &&
                        signinForm.controls['username'].errors?.email &&
                        signinForm.controls['username'].dirty">
                        Please enter a valid email address
                      </mat-error>
                      <mat-error
                        *ngIf="submitted &&
                        signinForm.controls['username'].errors?.required &&
                        signinForm.controls['username']">
                        Email is required
                      </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
                  </div>

                  <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="100">
                    <mat-form-field>
                      <input
                        matInput
                        placeholder="Password"
                        type="password"
                        formControlName="password"
                        value="{{password}}"
                        />
                      <mat-error
                        *ngIf="submitted &&
                        signinForm.controls['password'].errors?.required &&
                        signinForm.controls['password']">
                        Password is required
                      </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
                  </div>
                  <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="100">
                    <div class="_rem-me">
                      <mat-checkbox
                        color="primary"
                        class="_checkbox"
                        formControlName="ischeck">Remember me</mat-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="_forgot-link">
                      <a href="" class="_link">Forgot your username or password?</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </mat-card-content>
              <mat-card-actions>
                <div class="_button-row">
                  <button mat-raised-button color="primary">
                    Submit
                  </button>
                </div>
              </mat-card-actions>
            </mat-card>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

signin.component.ts 

import {Component, OnInit, Input }from '@angular/core'; 
import {ErrorStateMatcher }from '@angular/material/core'; 
import {
  FormControl, 
  FormGroup, 
  FormGroupDirective, 
  NgForm, 
  FormBuilder, 
  Validators
}from '@angular/forms'; 
import {SigninService }from '../../../services/signin/signin.service'; 
import {first }from 'rxjs/operators'; 
import {Router, ActivatedRoute }from '@angular/router'; 

/** Error when invalid control is dirty, touched, or submitted. */

@Component( {
  selector:'ap-signin', 
  templateUrl:'./signin.component.html', 
  styleUrls:['./signin.component.scss']
})
export class SigninComponent implements OnInit {
  // spinner
  pageLoaded:boolean; 
  @Input()diameter = 64; 
  @Input()strokeWidth = 7; 

  signinForm:FormGroup; 
  username:string; 
  password:string; 
  returnUrl:string; 
  submitted = false; 
  accessRequestForm = false; 

  //ischeck = true; 
  // matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();

  constructor(
    private signinService:SigninService, 
    private route:ActivatedRoute, 
    private router:Router, 
    private fb:FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.pageLoaded = false; 
    // redirect to dashboard if already signed in
    if (this.signinService.currentUserValue) {
      this.router.navigate(['/']); 
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() =>  {
      this.pageLoaded = true; 
    }, 500); 
    this.username = localStorage.getItem('username'); 
    this.password = localStorage.getItem('password'); 
    // Form validation
    this.formValidation(); 
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/'; 
  }

  // Form validation
  formValidation():void {
    this.signinForm = this.fb.group( {
      username:[null, [Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])]], 
      password:[null, [Validators.compose([Validators.required])]],
      ischeck: [false, Validators.required]
    }); 
  }

  get f() {
    return this.signinForm.controls; 
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true; 
    //alert(this.f.ischeck.value);
    if (this.signinForm.invalid) {
      return; 
    }
    this.pageLoaded = true; 
    this.signinService
      .signin(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data =>  {
          if (this.f.ischeck.value) {
          localStorage.setItem('username', this.f.username.value); 
          localStorage.setItem('password', this.f.password.value); 
          this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]); 
          }else {
            localStorage.clear(); 
            this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]); 
            }
        }, 
        err =>  {
          this.pageLoaded = false; 
        }); 
  }

}

signin.component.spec.ts

import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { SigninComponent } from './signin.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { CoreModule } from '../../core.module';
import { FeaturesModule } from '../../../features/features.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; 
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SigninService, User } from '../../../services/signin/signin.service'
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';


fdescribe('SigninComponent', () => {
  let signinComponent: SigninComponent;
  let signinService: SigninService;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SigninComponent>;
  let de: DebugElement;
  let el: HTMLElement;


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        CoreModule,
        FeaturesModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
      declarations: [ ],
      providers: [SigninService],

    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SigninComponent);
    signinComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
    //el = de.nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(signinComponent).toBeTruthy();
  });


  it('should call auth signin method', () => {
    let loginElement: DebugElement;
    const debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    let signinService = debugElement.injector.get(SigninService);
    let loginSpy = spyOn(signinService, 'signin').and.callThrough();
    loginElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('form'));
    signinComponent.signinForm.controls['username'].setValue('test@hp.com');
    signinComponent.signinForm.controls['password'].setValue('12345');
    loginElement.triggerEventHandler('ngSubmit', null);
    expect(loginSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);



  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a new fixture variable in the before each scope. You then try to access the fixture in the it block, but it has not been assigned to the fixture in the describe block.

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SigninComponent);  // <-- remove const
  });
```